# How to stop changing the view (object as camera)

Tags: 3d-view

I'm new to Blender and trying to create my first project.
I downloaded Blender 4.0.2, and kept all the default settings.
I watched some YouTube tutorials and everything was fine, except for one very strength thing:
Each time and after each select (left mouse), double click (left mouse), or any action, the view will change to focus on the object (object as camera). I did everything to disable it but I couldn't.
I watched many videos on YouTube and noticed that no one had this problem. I mean the left button selection should not move the view to another place.
could anybody help please!